# how to remvoe route parameter form $route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two forms one is blank from and other edit form. I need to get page name from route. I use var `formType = $route.current.originalPath.slice(1);` it work fine with blank from but when user click to edit the form I have route parameter in variable `formType = "rrn/:formId`. just I want how to remove :formId from $route and get 'rrn'

```
 var formType = $route.current.originalPath.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the $location service provided by Angular.

Ex: http://www.example.com/some/path

```
var path = $location.path();
// path = /some/path
var splitPath = path.split('/')
// splitPath[0] == 'some'
```

See docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location